# Creating new feature classes from rows in polygon feature class?

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, cursor

I'm trying really hard here to get an arcpy equivalent for ARCGIS' ModelBuilder's Iterate Feature Selection. I need to export the individual polygon rows in a feature class as new feature classes.

Any help?